# iOS: moving code from framework to main project causes retain cycles

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, ios-frameworks

I have an iOS app that contains a bunch of source files. I have a separate "Utilities" framework that I had been maintaining as a static framework. It was included in the "Embed Binaries" build stop. However it's becoming annoying when I need to make changes to this framework, and rebuild it.

To make this process more convenient I moved all of the source files into my main project and recompiled it. It builds correctly. However when I run the app all of my View Controllers are retained indefinitely!

It's the strangest thing. Any idea why moving the same code from a static framework to the main executable build would cause retain cycles? The utilities library contains a few UIViews, but no UIViewControllers. Yet all of the main UIViewControllers of the app are retained after the merge.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code involved in the retain cycles?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not really sure where the issue is occurring, so I'm not sure what I should even post. I'll do some digging in one of the affected view controllers and see if I can figure out what lines are causing the retain.